# find duplicate from combination of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table as below :-

```
SampleId1   SampleId2    
1              2    
1              2    
2              2    
3              2    
1              4 
2              4    
2              4    
3              5
```

I want to find duplicate combination

Eg. SampleId2 has duplicate value of SampleId1 on first two rows

Expected Result :-

```
SampleId1  SampleId2    
1             2    
2             4
```

I tried :-

```
SELECT
    SampleId1 , SampleId2, COUNT(*)
FROM
    tablename
GROUP BY
    SampleId1 , SampleId2
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

But this query is not giving me results as expected.

Comment: doesn't your query gives you the expected result ?

Comment: no.. It does not

Comment: so what do you get ?

Comment: What is not right about your current results?

Comment: It is not giving me combination as I was expecting. Eg. It gives me duplicate from both the columns

Comment: can you show us the current result with your query ?

Comment: [Your query is working exactly as expected](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=af96a6c76f8976793e26186a1d99a7e6).  You must have some typo happening.

Comment: I think you have simplified what you are doing, and our problem here is that your simplified version definitely does what you want.  I suspect you need to look at how your real version differs from the simple one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just don't want to project count result in your selection other wise your expected result and your query all the things 100% correct just remove count(*) from select

```
SELECT
    SampleId1 , SampleId2
FROM
    t
GROUP BY
    SampleId1 , SampleId2
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1

SampleId1   SampleId2
1             2
2             4
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want to remove the count in your query, so you can try with below one.

```
SELECT
    SampleId1 , SampleId2
FROM
    Test_group
GROUP BY
    SampleId1 , SampleId2
HAVING 
    COUNT(1) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to get duplicated rows and this is the solution

```
SELECT a.*
FROM docs a
JOIN (
    SELECT SampleId1, SampleId2, COUNT(*)
    FROM docs 
    GROUP BY SampleId1, SampleId2
    HAVING count(*) > 1 
) b
ON a.SampleId1 = b.SampleId1
AND a.SampleId2 = b.SampleId2
Group BY SampleId1
ORDER BY a.SampleId2
```

see the result [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33ae28/5/0)

Comment: Nope. Not fix. (1) `count(*)` expression should have an alias. (2) `SELECT a.*` with `GROUP BY a.SampleId1` ? Please test your query before posting it as an answer unless you are sure that your query is working

Comment: @Squirrel I tested [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33ae28/5/0) no problem with it

Comment: OP is not using `MySQL`